# Does Keep-Alive in WCF Use More Resources than Polling?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.5, keep-alive

I could probably setup a couple test-bed applications and find out, but I'm hoping someone has already experienced this or just simply has a more intuitive understanding.  I have three executables.  Two different clients (call them Client1.exe and Client2.exe) and a WCF service host (call it Host.exe) that hosts what's more or less a message bus type service for the two clients.  I won't get into the "why's" as that's a long story and not productive to this question.

The point is this, Client1 sends a request through this service to Client2. Client2 performs operations, then responds with results to Client1.  Client1 will always be initiator of requests, so this order of operations will always be consistent this way.  This also means that Client1 can open it's channels to communicate to this service as-needed, whereas due to the need of callback services, Client2 has to keep it's channels open.  I've began by attempting to keep-alive.  However, these are all three on the desktop and PC sleep events, or other issues (not sure) seem to interfere with it.  And once it times out, everything has to be restarted which makes it a real pain.  I have some ideas I may try to help the keep-alive approach, but this brought up a question that I don't have an answer to... is this the best use of my resources.

The way I figure it, there are two main approaches for Client2,

1. Keep-Alive with a lot of monitoring (timers and checking of connection states) and connection resetting code which would be faster since it could respond to requests immediately.  The downside is this has to be kept alive throughout the time that the user keeps Client2 open on their desktop which could be short and sweet to crazy-long.
2. Poll periodically for a request which would allow the resources to only be used when checking or processing a request from Client1.  This would be slower since poll requests would not be real-time, but would eliminate any external issue concerns disconnecting the service.  This would also cause me to have to add more state to the service.  It's already a PerSession service with a list of available instances of Client2 ID's so that Client1 knows which instance it's talking to, but it would add more.

Client2 performs many other functions and so still has to be very performant with this process, which makes me wonder which is most likely to cost in resources?  Is the polling approach more costly in resources?  Or attempting to keep-alive?

Comment: Can you even keep the state in memory? That would mean that any process exit (deployment, bug, reboot, bluescreen) loses data. Regarding cost: A null request costs almost nothing. You get like 10k per second per CPU core. So the polling cost mainly depends on what the server-side implementation does.

Comment: @usr: "Can you even keep the state in memory?" Yes... I'm only talking about storing the "request" sent from Client1 so that Client2 will find it once it polls for "jobs to complete."  So with your "Regarding cost" statement, are you saying that if I periodically poll for requests to complete that it costs almost nothing (minus what happens when checking for the requests in the service)?  How is that?  Wouldn't it cost to create and open the channel as well as close it?

Comment: Yeah, it costs *almost* nothing. Is .1ms in CPU time spent a lot for you? Probably not.

Comment: You could use long-polling. The client polls. The server returns any "events" that it has immediately. If no events are queued then it waits for up to 20s for new events (asynchronously for efficiency reasons). That's how AJAX long-polling works. You need one poll request per 20s interval and you have near zero latency.

Comment: That's a good time to benchmark from, but I was hoping to have it respond sooner for at least a "near real-time" experience for the user.  Preferrably within 1s of request.  That was why I originally started down the path of the keep-alive approach only to find that trying to do that poses it's own set of challenges.  Maybe polling too soon would then tie up the cores too much.  I hadn't considered that...

Comment: The server would respond immediately when there are events. It would not wait the full 20s. Near-zero latency.

Comment: Oh... my bad... I see.  I thought you meant it waited 20s to poll.  You're saying poll for 20s looking for events, close and re-poll.  That's a really good idea.  I may give that a try.

Comment: Google for AJAX long-polling to get explanations and implementation ideas.